# maximize summation of absolute difference of array by rearranging the array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

Arrange given array in a such a way that the `summation of the absolute differences between every two adjacent numbers is maximum`

array=( 1, 2, 7)
arrangement is `(1,7,2)`

```
sum=|1-7|+|7-2|=11
```

Comment: Please show what you have attempted and where you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in O(nlogn).Think before...

1. Sort the array 1 2 3 4 5
2. Select left=5 right=5 that is the maximum. i is 1 and j is 4 and i gives max absolute difference so

   ### 1-5 ==> sum+=|5-1|==>4
3. Append on its right or left based upon max absolute difference.Here its on right with i

   ### 1-5-2 ==> sum+=|5-2|==>7
4. Now left=1 and right=2 and 4 gives max difference with left so

   ### 4-1-5-2 ==> sum+=|4-1|==> 10
5. Finally its same difference for left and right with 3

   ### 3-4-1-5-2 or 4-1-5-2-3 ==> sum+=1==> 11

CODE:-(C++)

```
sort(a.begin(),a.end());
int l=a[a.size()-1]; //left
int r=l;             // right
int i=0,j=a.size()-2;
long long int sum=0;
while(i<j){
        int li=abs(l-a[i]),ri=abs(r-a[i]);
        int lj=abs(l-a[j]),rj=abs(r-a[j]);
        if(li>ri||lj>rj){ //left side
                if(li>lj){
                        sum+=li;
                        l=a[i++];
                }else{
                        sum+=lj;
                        l=a[j--];
                }
        }else{
                if(ri>rj){
                        sum+=ri;
                        r=a[i++];
                }else{
                        sum+=rj;
                        r=a[j--];
                }
        }
        //cout<<l<<"---"<<r<<"------"<<i<<"---"<<j<<"----------"<<sum<<endl;
}
sum+=MAX(abs(l-a[i]),abs(r-a[i]));
cout<<sum<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not included your attempt and your thought-process, it would be wrong to help you straight out to solve the problem. But, I can get you started..

**HINT:** A lot can be solved by arranging the array in some way. For example, if the array is arranged in some way that you can quickly pick the greatest and the smallest values from it, life is very easy.

> summation of the absolute differences between every two adjacent numbers is maximum

Absolute Difference means that the adjacent numbers should be as far from each other as possible on the number line. The maximum difference possible in the array is, of course, the difference between the greatest and the smallest numbers. So, they need to be rearranged adjacently. The remaining array also has a greatest and a smallest value, so you can repeat the above step for all.

Try this and come back if you get stuck up somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

this is in O(nlogn) time as sorting was also done.

```
int main()
 {
 int n;
 cin>>n;  
 ll arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  cin>>arr[i];
sort(arr,arr+n);
ll i=0,j=n-1,sum=0;
while(i<j){
 sum+= abs(arr[j]-arr[i]);
 i++;
 sum+= abs(arr[j]-arr[i]);
 j--;
}
cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```