# How to find the 'max absolute sum' of a function with a set of integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm trying to solve this problem in C++, struggling to find a solution that is O(1).

Given an input array of four integers (s), shuffle them into an order such that `F(s) = abs(s[0]-s[1]) + abs(s[1]-s[2])+ abs(s[2]-s[3])` is maximum (absolute).

If the integers are each unique, then there are a max of 24 possible shuffles.

e.g.

```
A=5, B=3, C=-1, D=5
```

Shuffled to

```
A=5, B=-1, C=5, D=3
```

Would result in

```
F(s) = 14;
```

This algorithm should be O(1).

Do note the mix of negative and positive integers.

```
F(s) = abs(s[0]-s[1]) + abs(s[1]-s[2])+ abs(s[2]-s[3])
```

Comment: `O(1)` with fixed size input makes little sense... as checking 24 possibilities is `O(1)`...

Comment: Maybe the setter of the assignment simply meant that the code should take a constant amount of time to run regardless of the input values (with a fixed size input of 4)? You'll need to go back to them to clarify what they mean as @Jarod42 is correct that `O(1)` doesn't make much sense for a fixed size input. What solutions have you found? What makes you think they aren't `O(1)`? Show a [mcve].

Comment: Check the 24 possibilities with several inputs. Do you see a pattern ? Do you have different strategy with only positive numbers ? Where are positive/negative values when mixing sign ? Where are min/max (absolute) values ?

Comment: w.l.o.g. you can consider only non-negative numbers, since the answer is unchanged if you add a constant to each value.

Comment: Related (but no answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995504/maximum-sum-of-absolute-differences-dynamic-programming

Comment: Solution with explanation (spoilers): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-absolute-difference-array/

Comment: @kvantour: little different as `abs(s[0]-s[3])` is missing for OP.

Comment: Related (but no upvoted solutions): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496769/maximize-summation-of-absolute-difference-of-array-by-rearranging-the-array

Comment: @kvantour: `{1, 8, 2, 4}` -> 15 whereas `{4, 1, 8, 2}` -> 16.

Comment: @Jarod42 interesting

Comment: @Jarod42 Agreed that checking a fixed set of permutations is constant time, but maybe the intent is that requiring O(1) rules out solutions for which the run time is a function of the magnitude of the inputs. I don't really have anything at stake here, I'm just trying to see how it could make sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you do all permutations from `0, a, a+b, a+b+c` (with `a`, `b`, `c` positive), you would see that maximum is reach for:

- `a, a+b+c, 0, a+b`
- and by symmetry `a+b, 0, a+b+c, a`

(resulting in `2*a + 3*b + 2*c`).

Unreadable solution ("sort" in place):

```
int rearrange(int (&a)[4])
{
    if (a[3] < a[2]) {
        std::swap(a[3], a[2]);
    } // a[2] <= a[3]
    if (a[1] < a[0]) {
        std::swap(a[1], a[0]);
    } // a[2] <= a[3] && a[0] <= a[1]
    if (a[0] < a[2]) {
        std::swap(a[0], a[2]);
    } // a[2] <= a[3] && a[2] <= a[0] <= a[1] -> a[2] is the min
    if (a[1] < a[3]) {
        std::swap(a[1], a[3]);
    } // a[2] <= a[3] <= a[1] && a[2] <= a[0] <= a[1] -> a[1] is the max
    if (a[3] < a[0]) {
        std::swap(a[3], a[0]);
    } // a[2] <= a[0] <= a[3] <= a[1]
    // as we know order, we might get rid of abs:
    // (a[1] - a[0]) + (a[1] - a[2]) + (a[3] - a[2]);
    return -a[0] + 2 * a[1] - 2 * a[2] + a[3];
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/O7PzfG)